# Why can't we have a single library containing React and React-DOM libraries in a single library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

Why can't we have a merged library with both React.JS and React-DOM.JS?

We have to import both the libraries in each and every web-application that I came across. Or are there any instances of creating web-apps where either of these works solo?

Comment: DOM refers to the web implementation; i guess there are also structures that could use React like Android or iOS views.

Comment: If you're building a react-native app or a library of React components to share among multiple applications, you don't need all the DOM functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `react` is the core and `react-dom` the renderer. This is not only for DOM (browsers) purposes. Plus, there is some cases when you want your custom react render, even for browser.

There is lists of renderers you can plug on react here (+ some learning links) : https://github.com/chentsulin/awesome-react-renderer